# Failing to configure two HttpSecurity setups with JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have followed the advice from the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) on how to configure two separate `HttpSecurity` instances:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SoWebSecurityConfig
{
  @Autowired public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(username -> {
      log.info("\n\n\n *********  authenticating {} ************************************\n\n\n", username);
      return new User(username, "", asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("TV")));
    });
  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class SwiperSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { configureHttpSec(http, "/swiper"); }
  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(2)
  public static class TvSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { configureHttpSec(http, "/tv"); }
  }

  static HttpSecurity configureHttpSec(HttpSecurity http, String urlBase) throws Exception {
    http   .csrf().disable()
           .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    .and() .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(urlBase+"/**").authenticated()
    .and() .httpBasic()
    .and() .logout().logoutUrl(urlBase+"/logout").logoutSuccessHandler((req,resp,auth) -> {})
    ;
    return http;
  }
}
```

In the logs I do see two filter chains being created:

```
2014-06-30 12:44:22 main INFO  o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.as
ync.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@806996, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1937eaff, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71e4b308, org.springfr
amework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1d1cbd0f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@9b9a327, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCach
eAwareFilter@4993febc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@67064bdc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@78b612c6, org.s
pringframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6d11ceef, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6e7c351d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurit
yInterceptor@571a01f9] 
2014-06-30 12:44:22 main INFO  o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.as
ync.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@30c1da48, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@427ae189, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4784efd9, org.spring
framework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@187e5235, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@514de325, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestC
acheAwareFilter@16a9eb2e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@76332405, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@43a65cd8, or
g.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3fba233d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@376c7d7d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecu
rityInterceptor@3b48e183]
```

but only the one I designate with `Order(1)` will actually get used; the URLs matching the other one will not get authenticated.

I have also tried following the docs more closely, using `anyRequest()` instead of ant matchers for the `@Order(2)` configuration, but the result was the same.

What are my options to get around this problem?

I am using Spring 4.0.5, Spring Security 3.2.4.

Comment: Have you tried replacing configureHttpSec(http, "/tv"); with http.antMatcher("/tv") and http.antMatcher("/swipe") and building authorisation profiles under each to reflect the differences?

Comment: @Aeseir That's exactly what my problem was :) great eye! I read the documentation's example several times, but still missed this subtle difference of where the ant matcher is applied. Please undelete your answer so I can accept it. I'll edit it a bit to better accentuate the cause of the problem and the solution.

Comment: Done. Glad i was able to assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have failed to follow the documentation in one crucial aspect. You have

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(urlBase+"/**").authenticated()
```

which means that you register this `HttpSecurity` as a global security module, which applies to *all* URLs, but only requires authentication on those selected with the Ant matcher. When you do this twice, you end up with two chained global security modules, so naturally only the first one will be responsible for all URLs.

The documentation instead advises this:

```
http.antMatcher(urlBase+"/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
```

which means that the Ant matcher will used to select which URL this security module is responsible for, and bypass it for all others. This way the second module in line gets its chance when appropriate.

So all you need to do is slightly adjust your static configurer method to the following:

```
  static HttpSecurity configureHttpSec(HttpSecurity http, String urlBase) throws Exception {
    http   .csrf().disable()
           .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    .and() .antMatchers(urlBase+"/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and() .httpBasic()
    .and() .logout().logoutUrl(urlBase+"/logout").logoutSuccessHandler((req,resp,auth) -> {})
    ;
    return http;
  }
```